# Android mediaplayer Visualizer

Tags: android

The mediaplayer is inside service, but the visualizer is inside activity. In visualizer class, I need the mediaplayer as parameter to visualize, How to implement this?

The mediaplayer cannot be passed to visualizer class.

Comment: Following the link KYOGS posted is pretty simple and a great implementation of visualizer as I have used it in a project very recently along with `mediaplayer` in a service.

Answer (score 1):

[visualizer](http://kyogs.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-audioeffect.html) refer this one.hop its useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, you are right, we can visualize through audio session id. but ... I am using vitamio player, which doesn't support audio session id.